# Floating point numbers, precision, and Parsec

Tags: haskell, floating-point, parsec

Consider the following code:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Language
import Text.Parsec.String
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as Token

float :: Parser Double
float = Token.float (Token.makeTokenParser emptyDef)

myTest :: String -> Either ParseError Double
myTest = parse float ""
```

Now, thanks to QuickCheck I know a magic number (I have aligned result for
convenience):

```
λ> myTest "4.23808622486133"
Right      4.2380862248613305
```

Some floating point numbers cannot be exactly represented in memory, some
operations easily introduce «fluctuations» into floating point numbers. We
all know that. However, cause of this parsing problem seems to be different.

A few words about tests that helped me discover this… feature. Put simply,
in these tests floating point value is generated, printed, and parsed back
(with Parsec). For example, number `9.2` is known to be [impossible to
represent as floating
point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate),
however it passes the tests (obviously because of «smart» printing
function). Why does `4.23808622486133` fail?

---

For those who believe that these numbers are the same and `4.23808622486133` is just shortest unambiguous representation of `4.2380862248613305`:

```
a1 :: Double
a1 = 9.2000000000000003

a2 :: Double
a2 = 9.200000000000001

b1 :: Double
b1 = 4.23808622486133

b2 :: Double
b2 = 4.2380862248613305
```

Now:

```
λ> a1 == a2
True
λ> b1 == b2
False
```

Comment: Some people will disagree now again, but I'll keep saying: when you're using floating-point, you should _never expect anything to be exactly-equal_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, absolutely correct. However it's interesting why this sort of thing happens in parsing. I mean, suppose there is a number `x` that cannot be represented exactly as floating point number, but when it's printed, let's say there is `x'` number that is actually printed. When you parse it back, you should get `x` again. I expect that there is some kind of consistency in that...

Comment: I regret having written my answer. Could you unaccept it please? The other one seems more useful to Haskell programmers.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I've seen your discussion with DanielWagner and I understand why you want me to unaccept the answer. However, I think your answer is great, because it provides firm evidence that that bug does exist. This bug is in a third party library, Parsec, not in GHC. Theoretical part of your answer is also enlightening. I think your answer should not be unaccepted because of one downvote. Thank you again for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still not fixed in Parsec. If this exact problem breaks your day, take a look at [Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec), which is a fork of Parsec that fixes many bugs and conceptual flaws, improves quality of error messages and more.

As you can see this problem is fixed there:

```
λ> parseTest float "4.23808622486133"
4.23808622486133
λ> parseTest float "4.2380862248613305"
4.2380862248613305
```

---

*Disclosure*: I'm one of the authors of Megaparsec.

Comment: When discussing your own projects/packages on SO, you are expected to disclose your connection to them.

Answer (score 3):

Parsec does the conversion to Double using what amounts to

```
foldr (\d acc -> read [d] + acc / 10) 0 "423808622486133" :: Double
```

and as you point out, this is not equal to

```
423808622486133 / 100000000000000 :: Double
```

I agree that this should be considered a bug in Parsec.